# How can I access the property of a parent Class correctly in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working at a an Interface for an iPhone App. I recognised that I have repeating objects in my different views so i want to make a parent ViewController. But now when I want to acces a property of this parent ViewController from a child ViewController I get some problems. To be specific I want to have a general ProgressView in each View but I want it to be hidden when the View appears. When I access the ProgressView.hidden from the child ViewController to get it the ProgressView shown i get no errormessage, but at the running programm nothing happens.

My Code looks like this:

ParentViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController{
    UIProgressView *progressView;
}

@property (readwrite) UIProgressView *progressView;

@end
```

ParentViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    CGRect progressViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 407, 320, 9);
    progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:progressViewFrame];
    progressView.hidden = TRUE;
    [self.view addSubview:progressView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

ChildViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ToolbarViewController.h"

@interface ChildViewController : ParentViewController

@end
```

ChildViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    progressView.hidden = FALSE;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

if i do it like this the ProgressView Bar stays hidden and i get no errors. I also checked whether the viewDidLoad method was called and yes it gets called.

greetings
C4rmel

Answer (score 4):

When you call `progressView.hidden = FALSE;` before calling `[super viewDidLoad];`, the `progressView` has not been initialized yet; it is still `nil`, so the assignment has no effect.

Comment: I think he should keep it in viewDidLoad or move it to loadView. A view controller shouldn't create views on init. In any case, the subclass' viewDidLoad could call super first.

Comment: I agree with @ranReloaded. This should be in `-viewDidLoad` or in `-loadView` if he's creating the view programmatically.

Comment: @ranReloaded You are correct, I answered the question as if it were about a view, not a view controller. In fact, I even gave an example with the signature suitable for initializing a `UIView` instance.

Comment: @JasonCoco You're right, please see the comment and the edit.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Correct! UIView subclasses should create child views on initializer; UIViewControllers should create child views on either -loadView (if implemented) or -viewDidLoad (most common case)

Answer (score 3):

In the ChildViewController.m, the function calling sequence is incorrect.
Change it by below way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    progressView.hidden = FALSE;    
}
```

Here call to super will create progressView. Then you can hide it. Otherwise you are hiding a view which is not even created.